# How to translate foreign characters to create String printable in spinners

Tags: android

I need to create a spinner based on titles read from several html files.
For Czech for example, the text is well displayed in the webview but when I set this text

```
2.lanovka p&#345;ijedep&#345;ed zav&#345;ené dve&#345;e
```

in the spinner, I get unpritable characters.

In Russian, html text is this one:

```
&#1043;&#1086;&#1083;&#1086;&#1089;&#1046;&#1102;&#1083;&#1103; &#1042;&#1077;&#1088;&#1085;&#1072;
```

I tried to use Html.fromHtml() without success. I'm not really sure it's for this purpose as I don't know anything about html encoding.

Can I have any help?

Regards,
Alain

Comment: While reading from those html pages you're not accounting for the character encoding.

Comment: Sorry greenapps, I don't really understand you!

Comment: Hum well, I first tried Html.fromHtml() without success, certainly because another mistake but in fact it works. Only some characters like " could cause problem but in fact the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hum well, I first tried Html.fromHtml() without success, certainly because another mistake but in fact it works. Only some characters like " could cause problem but globally the problem is solved.